# Continuously complinig and running my coffeescript tests with karma

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs, karma-runner, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-coffee

I'm using grunt, karma (`singleRun: false`). My tests are written in coffeescript. Each time my coffee file changes I want my tests to run. The problem is that I don't know how to make both happens. 
So far I discovered the watch task, I tried to add my coffee thing there and add the watcher to my test task like that:

```
//karma.conf.js
singleRun: true,
```

and in Gruntfile:

```
//Gruntfile.js
watch: {
  coffee: {
            files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.coffee'],
            tasks: 'coffee'
        }
}
grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'coffee',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma',
    'watch:coffee'
]);
```

This way the karma watcher is watching javascript files, but my own coffee watcher is not triggered at all.

Right now I just removed `watch:coffee` from test task and I'm running `grunt test` and `grunt watch:coffee` in parallel terminals, which looks a bit pathetic. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Much better approach is to use the [karma-coffee-preprocessor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coffee-preprocessor). It's simple to set up and I can use `singleRun: true`.